# Why git command commit doesn't work on github.com?

Tags: github, git-commit

After making some changes and typing required add commands, I executed `commit`. If I check git log I can see that commit has worked but when I check the repository on [Github](https://github.com/) I don't see any of the changes I've done. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You committed on your local repository, you need to push the commit on your github repository

Comment: :S sooo noob! Thanks you @CharlesB

Comment: Thanks you too for correcting, @Ikmhr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your reference i add the command here

```
git init

git add .

git commit -m "Made chang"

git push
```